# Error: Class 'Object' not found in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this component in my app:

```
<?php
class ImageComponent extends Object {
    var $name = 'Image';
    private $file;
    private $image;
    private $info;
    public function prepare($file) {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $this->file = $file;
            $info = getimagesize($file);
            $this->info = array(
                'width'  => $info[0],
                'height' => $info[1],
                'bits'   => $info['bits'],
                'mime'   => $info['mime']
            );
            $this->image = $this->create($file);
        } else {
            exit('Error: Could not load image ' . $file . '!');
        }
    }
    public function create($image) {
        $mime = $this->info['mime'];
        if ($mime == 'image/gif') {
            return imagecreatefromgif($image);
        } elseif ($mime == 'image/png') {
            return imagecreatefrompng($image);
        } elseif ($mime == 'image/jpeg') {
            return imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        }
    }   
    public function save($file, $quality = 100) {
        $info = pathinfo($file);
        $extension = strtolower($info['extension']);
        if ($extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'jpg') {
            imagejpeg($this->image, $file, $quality);
        } elseif($extension == 'png') {
            imagepng($this->image, $file, 0);
        } elseif($extension == 'gif') {
            imagegif($this->image, $file);
        }
        imagedestroy($this->image);
    }       
    public function resize($width = 0, $height = 0,$r=255,$g=255,$b=255,$ratio=true) {
        if (!$this->info['width'] || !$this->info['height']) {
            return;
        }
        $xpos = 0;
        $ypos = 0;
        $scale = min($width / $this->info['width'], $height / $this->info['height']);
        if ($scale == 1) {
            return;
        }
        if($ratio!=false)
        {
            $new_width = (int)($this->info['width'] * $scale);
            $new_height = (int)($this->info['height'] * $scale);            
            $xpos = (int)(($width - $new_width) / 2);
            $ypos = (int)(($height - $new_height) / 2);
            $image_old = $this->image;
            $this->image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
            if (isset($this->info['mime']) && $this->info['mime'] == 'image/png') {     
                imagealphablending($this->image, false);
                imagesavealpha($this->image, true);
                $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->image, $r, $g, $b, 127);
                imagecolortransparent($this->image, $background);
            } else {
                $background = imagecolorallocate($this->image, $r, $g, $b);
            }
            imagefilledrectangle($this->image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $background);
            imagecopyresampled($this->image, $image_old, $xpos, $ypos, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $this->info['width'], $this->info['height']);
            imagedestroy($image_old);
            $this->info['width']  = $width;
            $this->info['height'] = $height;
        }
        else
        {
            $new_width = (int)($width);
            $new_height = (int)($height);           
            $xpos = (int)(($width - $new_width) / 2);
            $ypos = (int)(($height - $new_height) / 2);
            $image_old = $this->image;
            $this->image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
            if (isset($this->info['mime']) && $this->info['mime'] == 'image/png') {     
                imagealphablending($this->image, false);
                imagesavealpha($this->image, true);
                $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->image, $r, $g, $b, 127);
                imagecolortransparent($this->image, $background);
            } else {
                $background = imagecolorallocate($this->image, $r, $g, $b);
            }
            imagefilledrectangle($this->image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $background);
            imagecopyresampled($this->image, $image_old, $xpos, $ypos, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $this->info['width'], $this->info['height']);
            imagedestroy($image_old);
            $this->info['width']  = $width;
            $this->info['height'] = $height;
        }
    }
    public function watermark($file, $position = 'bottomright') {
        $watermark = $this->create($file);
        $watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
        $watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);
        switch($position) {
            case 'topleft':
            $watermark_pos_x = 0;
            $watermark_pos_y = 0;
            break;
            case 'topright':
            $watermark_pos_x = $this->info['width'] - $watermark_width;
            $watermark_pos_y = 0;
            break;
            case 'bottomleft':
            $watermark_pos_x = 0;
            $watermark_pos_y = $this->info['height'] - $watermark_height;
            break;
            case 'bottomright':
            $watermark_pos_x = $this->info['width'] - $watermark_width;
            $watermark_pos_y = $this->info['height'] - $watermark_height;
            break;
        }
        imagecopy($this->image, $watermark, $watermark_pos_x, $watermark_pos_y, 0, 0, 120, 40);
        imagedestroy($watermark);
    }
    public function crop($top_x, $top_y, $bottom_x, $bottom_y) {
        $image_old = $this->image;
        $this->image = imagecreatetruecolor($bottom_x - $top_x, $bottom_y - $top_y);
        imagecopy($this->image, $image_old, 0, 0, $top_x, $top_y, $this->info['width'], $this->info['height']);
        imagedestroy($image_old);
        $this->info['width'] = $bottom_x - $top_x;
        $this->info['height'] = $bottom_y - $top_y;
    }
    public function rotate($degree, $color = 'FFFFFF') {
        $rgb = $this->html2rgb($color);
        $this->image = imagerotate($this->image, $degree, imagecolorallocate($this->image, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]));
        $this->info['width'] = imagesx($this->image);
        $this->info['height'] = imagesy($this->image);
    }
    private function filter($filter) {
        imagefilter($this->image, $filter);
    }
    private function text($text, $x = 0, $y = 0, $size = 5, $color = '000000') {
        $rgb = $this->html2rgb($color);
        imagestring($this->image, $size, $x, $y, $text, imagecolorallocate($this->image, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]));
    }
    private function merge($file, $x = 0, $y = 0, $opacity = 100) {
        $merge = $this->create($file);
        $merge_width = imagesx($image);
        $merge_height = imagesy($image);
        imagecopymerge($this->image, $merge, $x, $y, 0, 0, $merge_width, $merge_height, $opacity);
    }
    private function html2rgb($color) {
        if ($color[0] == '#') {
            $color = substr($color, 1);
        }
        if (strlen($color) == 6) {
            list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0] . $color[1], $color[2] . $color[3], $color[4] . $color[5]);   
        } elseif (strlen($color) == 3) {
            list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0] . $color[0], $color[1] . $color[1], $color[2] . $color[2]);    
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $r = hexdec($r); 
        $g = hexdec($g); 
        $b = hexdec($b);    
        return array($r, $g, $b);
    }
    public  function roundcorner($sourceImageFile, $outputfile,$radius='8') {
        # test source image
        if (file_exists($sourceImageFile)) {
            $res = is_array($info = getimagesize($sourceImageFile));
        } 
        else $res = false;
        # open image
        if ($res) {
            $w = $info[0];
            $h = $info[1];
            switch ($info['mime']) {
                case 'image/jpeg': $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceImageFile);
                break;
                case 'image/gif': $src = imagecreatefromgif($sourceImageFile);
                break;
                case 'image/png': $src = imagecreatefrompng($sourceImageFile);
                break;
                default: 
                $res = false;
            }
        }
        # create corners
        if ($res) {
            $q = 10; # change this if you want
            $radius *= $q;
            # find unique color
            do {
                $r = rand(0, 255);
                $g = rand(0, 255);
                $b = rand(0, 255);
            }
            while (imagecolorexact($src, $r, $g, $b) < 0);
            $nw = $w*$q;
            $nh = $h*$q;
            $img = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
            $alphacolor = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, $r, $g, $b, 127);
            imagealphablending($img, false);
            imagesavealpha($img, true);
            imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $alphacolor);
            imagefill($img, 0, 0, $alphacolor);
            imagecopyresampled($img, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $w, $h);
            imagearc($img, $radius-1, $radius-1, $radius*2, $radius*2, 180, 270, $alphacolor);
            imagefilltoborder($img, 0, 0, $alphacolor, $alphacolor);
            imagearc($img, $nw-$radius, $radius-1, $radius*2, $radius*2, 270, 0, $alphacolor);
            imagefilltoborder($img, $nw-1, 0, $alphacolor, $alphacolor);
            imagearc($img, $radius-1, $nh-$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, 90, 180, $alphacolor);
            imagefilltoborder($img, 0, $nh-1, $alphacolor, $alphacolor);
            imagearc($img, $nw-$radius, $nh-$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, 0, 90, $alphacolor);
            imagefilltoborder($img, $nw-1, $nh-1, $alphacolor, $alphacolor);
            imagealphablending($img, true);
            imagecolortransparent($img, $alphacolor);
            # resize image down
            $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
            imagealphablending($dest, false);
            imagesavealpha($dest, true);
            imagefilledrectangle($dest, 0, 0, $w, $h, $alphacolor);
            imagecopyresampled($dest, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $nw, $nh);
            $res = $dest;
            imagepng( $res,$outputfile );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I load the component in MyController :

```
  App::import('Component', 'Image');
  $MyImageCom = new ImageComponent();
```

But, when I just load the component, I recieve this error:

> Error: Class 'Object' not found File:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aurum/app/Controller/Component/ImageComponent.php
>   Line: 2

Comment: extends Object -> extends Component ?

Comment: Its worked now.I changed Object to Component.But I download this code from the Cakephp Image Component.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that plugin/component. Maybe it's an old code that isn't suitable for the the new version of Cakephp. If my answer helped you, please approve it.

Comment: First learn how to debug in php, the error is pretty obvious. And what makes you think that code, that you got from somewhere has to work? Further this code might work but it is not very well written nor a good implementation in the MVC context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're extending a class which isn't exists.
Instead of:

```
 class ImageComponent extends Object {
```

Use:

```
 class ImageComponent extends Component {
```

Example [From Cakephp manual](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component):

```
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');

class MathComponent extends Component { //not Object
    public function doComplexOperation($amount1, $amount2) {
        return $amount1 + $amount2;
    }
}
```